# C++ - Send data in one ostream to another ostream

Tags: c++, iostream

I don't understand what this ostream function declaration means:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
```

(specifically, the `(*pf)(ostream&)` part). I want to do something like:

```
void print(ostream& os){
    cout << os;
}
```

but I get the error:

```
 Invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' . . . and 'ostream')
```

Comment: That one's for manipulators.

Comment: Expanding on chris' comment, declare a function `std::ostream& foo(std::ostream& os) { return os << "foo"; }` then in your main code try `std::cout << foo << std::endl;` Then step through in a debugger. you'll see soon-enough how it works.

Comment: @IInspectable: Firefox is unable to find the word `const` on this page anywhere else than in your comment. so who is the "you" you refer to, and where is the `const` that you refer to?

Comment: your print function signature should be:  `ostream& print(ostream& os);` if you want to pass it to that operator. The operator signature looks like it takes a function pointer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand what this ostream function declaration means:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
```

Have you seen functions like `std::endl`, `std::flush`, `std::hex`, `std::dec`, `std::setw`...?  They can all be "sent" to a stream using "<<", then they get called with the stream as a function argument and do their magic on the stream.  They actually match the `ostream& (*pf)(ostream&)` argument above, and that operator's the one that lets them be used.  If we look at the Visual C++ implementation...

```
 _Myt& operator<<(_Myt& (__cdecl *_Pfn)(_Myt&))
 {
      return ((*_Pfn)(*this));
 }
```

...you can see if just calls the function, passing the stream it's used on as an argument.  The functions are expected to return a reference to the same stream argument, so that further `<<` operations may be chained, or the stream may be implicitly converted to `bool` as a test of stream state.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip for more information about io manipulators.

You wanted help with:

```
void print(ostream& os){
    cout << os;
}
```

The issue here is that you're sending the `ostream` argument to another stream - `cout` - and it doesn't know what you want it to do with it.

To send the current *content* of `os` to `cout`, try:

```
void print(ostream& os){
    cout << os.rdbuf();
}
```

Or if you want to print some actual data to the stream represented by the argument:

```
void print(ostream& os){
    os << "show this!\n";
}

print(std::cout);   // to write "show this!\n" to `std::cout`
print(std::cerr);   // to write "show this!\n" to `std::cerr`
```

Comment: Referring to std::endl, etc. was especially helpful. I actually want to append the contents of one ostream to another (which may show I don't really know what ostream is).

Comment: @thethuthinnang: that makes perfect sense... often useful for copying data you've prepared in a stringstream on to a file or stdout/err... just use `cout << os.rdbuf();`.

Answer (score 3):

### What the declaration means.

The formal argument …

```
ostream& (*pf)(ostream&)
```

declares an argument named `pf` which is a pointer, to which you can apply an argument parenthesis with an `ostream&` argument, which constitutes a call that returns an `ostream&` as its result.

It can be simplified to just  …

```
ostream& pf(ostream&)
```

where you can more easily see that it's a function.

The drawback is that this form is seldom used, so not everybody is aware that it decays to the first form (much the same as e.g. `int x[43]` as a formal argument type is effectively the same as just `int x[]` because both these forms decay to just `int* x` in the function type, so that in the function body you can even increment that `x`).

---

### What it’s used for.

A function of the above form is usually an output stream **manipulator**. That means, you can pass it to the `<<` output operator. What happens then is just that `<<` calls that function, with the stream as argument, as specified by C++11 §27.7.3.6.3/1 and 2:

> `basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<`
>   `(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&))`
>
> 1. Effects: None. Does not behave as a formatted output function (as described in 27.7.3.6.1).
> 2. Returns: `pf(*this)`.

There is also an overload of `<<` that takes a similar function, but with `std::basic_ios&` argument and result, and one that takes a function with `std::ios_base` argument and result.

Class `std::ios_base` is the base of the iostreams class hierarchy and the standard manipulators defined at that level are …:

- *Format flag manipulators:*
  `boolalpha`, `noboolalpha`, `showbase`, `noshowbase`, `showpoint`, `noshowpoint`, `showpos`, `noshowpos`, `skipws`, `noskipws`, `uppercase`, `nouppercase`, `unitbut` and `nounitbuf`.
- *Adjustment field manipulators:*
  `internal`, `left` and `right`.
- *Numeral system base manipulators:*
  `dec`, `hex` and `oct`.
- *Floating point number presentation manipulators:*
  `fixed`, `scientific`, `hexfloat` and `defaultfloat`.

Manipulators that take user arguments don’t follow this form and those that the standard provides are in a separate header called `<iomanip>`.

### Example: a user-defined manipulator.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// With Visual C++, if necessary define __func__ as __FUNCTION__.
using namespace std;

class Logger
{
private:
    string  funcname_;
    static int call_level;

    auto
    static indent( ostream& stream )
        -> ostream&
    { return (stream << string( 4*call_level, ' ' )); }

public:
    Logger( string const& funcname )
        : funcname_( funcname )
    {
        clog << indent << "-> " << funcname_ << endl;
        ++call_level;
    }

    ~Logger()
    {
        --call_level;
        clog << indent << "<- " << funcname_ << endl;
    }
};

int Logger::call_level = 0;

#define WITH_LOGGING Logger logging( __func__ )

void c() { WITH_LOGGING; }
void b() { WITH_LOGGING; c(); }
void a() { WITH_LOGGING; b(); }

auto main() -> int { a(); }
```

Output, which shows the calls and returns, nicely indented:

```
-> a
    -> b
        -> c
        <- c
    <- b
<- a
```

Comment: @TonyD: yes, but how do you propose to detect the difference? :-)

Comment: @Tony: "lvalue to rvalue conversion" cannot apply to function argument type adjustment, so it's irrelevant. And limits on the number of such conversions is irrelevant. I'm sorry that I didn't check (in the sense of read closely) your original quote, but it's of course also irrelevant, it's just that it *seemed* about right. The relevant part of the standard is §8.3.5/5, "After
determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is
adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively". AFAIK the diff is undetectable.

Comment: @TonyD: sorry, nope, regarding "given an actual int[43] parameter you can match template <size_t N> void f(int (&x)[N]) - which is an extremely useful way to capture the array dimension.". This isn't an example where formal argument type decay is in the picture.

Comment: @TonyD: well the original context was formal argument type, so that's what it was all about. and you're right that it's possible to choose an interpretation (namely as a description of the details of how the standards committee chose to specify the effect) where it's wrong. that means that that interpretation is wrong. ;-)

Comment: Uhm, I'll fix the wording so it's less easy to misunderstand. But gimme some time. It's late night here.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter portion of the declaration:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
```

is a *function pointer* syntax.

The expression:

```
ostream& (*pf)(ostream&)
```

Declares a pointer to a function, pf, that takes an `ostream&` parameter and returns a reference to an `ostream`.

If I declare a function:

```
ostream& my_function(ostream& output);
```

Then I can pass a pointer to the function as the parameter:

```
operator<< (my_function);
```

Read up on function pointer syntax.  Search the web and stackoverflow.