# Appending an ostream which is the empty string prevents further appends

Tags: c++, append, ostream

This program does not work as I expect. It outputs "abc", but I expected "abcxyz". Appending a stream containing the empty string to a stream, causes the streampos to be set to -1 and no more data can be appended to it. 
I was using the technique from [C++ - Send data in one ostream to another ostream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20850065/669678) but it doesn't work if one of the streams happens to be empty. I had thought that maybe rdbuf() was returning `nullptr` in this case, so I checked for that. It isn't null, but whatever it does return is not making the downstream happy. Commenting out the line: `out << b.rdbuf();` causes it to output "abcxyz" as expected. What is the proper way to append ostreams which might happen to be empty?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::stringstream a, b, c, out;

    a << "abc";
    b << "";
    c << "xyz";

    out << a.rdbuf();
                printf("after A out.tellp = %qd\n", (int64_t)out.tellp());
    out << b.rdbuf();
                printf("after B out.tellp = %qd\n", (int64_t)out.tellp());
    out << c.rdbuf();
                printf("after C out.tellp = %qd\n", (int64_t)out.tellp());

    std::cout << out.rdbuf() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
after A out.tellp = 3
after B out.tellp = -1
after C out.tellp = -1
abc
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

---

edit: A fixed version. Is there a better way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <class T, class U>
void append(T& a, U& b) 
{
    if (int64_t(b.tellp()) <= 0) return;
    a << b.rdbuf();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::stringstream a, b, c;

    a << "abc";
    b << "";
    c << "xyz";

    append(std::cout, a);
    append(std::cout, b);
    append(std::cout, c);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of [`std::ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)? "_If no characters were inserted, executes `setstate(failbit)`._" How many characters are in `b.rdbuf ()`?

Comment: I would have assumed that meant no characters were inserted due to an actual failure, not because the stream is legitimately empty. So it is required to check every time you want to use '<<' that the stream is not empty? And is tellp() the proper way to do that?

Comment: My answer to that: read the documentation; don't assume anything. If you read the link to the documentation provided, only the overload that accepts `std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>*` as an argument does this. Use different overloads, if this behavior is undesirable.

Comment: Why not just use `str()` instead of `rdbuf()`?

Comment: Thanks. ```str()``` is an extra allocation for the intermediate string. Probably not a big deal for my current use. But I think I'll still use the ```tellp()``` check above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::basic_ios::good()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) and [std::basic_ios::clear()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) for what you want to achieve.

Following is example code. See [it working here](https://ideone.com/KVXfrz):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    std::stringstream a;
    std::stringstream b;
    std::stringstream c;
    std::stringstream out;

    a << "abc";
    b << "";
    c << "xyz";

    out << a.rdbuf();
    printf("after A out.tellp = %qd\n", (int64_t)out.tellp());

    out << b.rdbuf();
    if( ! out.good() )
    {
        std::cout<< "It is not good!!!" << std::endl;
        out.clear();
    }
    printf("after B out.tellp = %qd\n", (int64_t)out.tellp());

    out << c.rdbuf();
    printf("after C out.tellp = %qd\n", (int64_t)out.tellp());

    std::cout << out.rdbuf() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This clears / ignores any failure, not just empty stream.